# Help in identifying an unknown Golden Worm/Larvae

Tags: species-identification, invertebrates

Can anyone help me to recognize this type of species? Is it a clustered worms or clustered larvae? Location is in Bali, Indonesia. Recently this species is goes viral, but people here always link this species to a myth. 
Thanks. [image: Is this worms or larvae ?]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are larvae of the so called [fungus gnat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fungus_gnat) of the order *Diptera*. Fungus gnats are small flying insects that look sort of like mosquitoes but they don’t bite. In fact, adult fungus gnats live only about 7-10 days and do not feed. It is the immature larval form that can cause damage to your plants.

[image]
Source: https://www.projectnoah.org/spottings/30766835/fullscreen

I see, i'm Balinese too, you know everything things were rare are linked to myth.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. It seems like you have identified the species but we prefer these answer to include a link and/or some photos that confirm the identification. You can `edit` the question to include these.